# Change UIImage View on orientation change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to change the `UIImageView` image when the device goes into landscape orientation. I have the orientation working but am rather new to Objective-C and finding it difficult to change the image. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong and help me fix this It would be really helpful. Thanks for your time.

**Set up**
Storyboard with navigation controller and WelcomeViewController

**WelcomeViewController.h File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WelcomeViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageToDisplay;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageToDisplay;

@end
```

**WelcomeViewController.m File**

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"


@interface WelcomeViewController ()
@end


@implementation WelcomeViewController

@synthesize imageToDisplay;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation     
{
    UIDeviceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == 
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        // removing @2x.png from imageNamed string worked
        imageToDisplay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome@2x.png"];
    }

    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || 
toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        // removing @2x.png from imageNamed string worked
        imageToDisplay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome-landscape@2x.png"];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: 1) Don't use the `@2x` suffix for images. Cocoa automatically loads the correct ones depending of device. 2) Do you have a XIB or Storyboard with an *imageView*? In that case, you need to connect it to your `imageToDisplay` property rather than using *synthesize*.

Comment: Thanks for 1) the tip about the image loading and 2) for pointing out to connect my UIImageView component to the property. I selected the UIImageView component and using control drag connected it to the @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageToDisplay;

Now when I rotate the device the image disappears which I think is the result of inappropriate syntax on my behalf. I am using imageToDisplay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome-landscape.png"]; which is leaving my app with a black screen on orientation change

Comment: Double check that you are writing the name of your image correctly and make sure the image is added to the project. Note that iOS devices are case sensitive regarding filenames.

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez Thanks, after connecting the IBOutlet to the property, and removing the file extension from the the UIImageView file name it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting from my comments*

1) Don't use the @2x suffix for images. Cocoa automatically loads the correct ones depending of device.

2) Do you have a XIB or Storyboard with an imageView? In that case, you need to connect it to your imageToDisplay property rather than using synthesize.

3) Double check that you are writing the name of your image correctly and make sure the image is added to the project. Note that iOS devices are case sensitive regarding filenames.